# In the sentence, is the word 'so' an intensifier?

Tags: word-usage

I have read a sentence on line. In the sentence, is the word 'so' an intensifier? Please explain it.

> If their number increased at all, it did so very slowly; indeed, sometimes it may have even decreased.

Answer (score 2):

No, **so** is not an intensifier there. It's something called [**an adverb of manner**](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/adverbs-manner/). Adverbs of manner are adverbs that are used to tell you the way or how something is done. In your example, it tells you how their number increased. It increased very slowly if at all. And then it goes on to tell you that, in fact, it may have even decreased.

Example:

> How did you manage to get away with this?
>   I did **so** by using an anonymously registered public account.

In this example, you can mentally substitute **I did so by** with **I managed to get away with this by** and it will mean exactly the same thing.